# One to One or zero relationship in Entity Framework and both Entities have their own PKs

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to create One to One or zero relationship in Entity Framework and both Entities have their own PKs but I couldn't

```
public class EmployeeBank
{
        [Key]
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public Name {get;set;}
        public virtual EmployeePaymentMethod EmployeePaymentMethod { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeePaymentMethod
{
        [Key]
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public virtual EmployeeBank EmployeeBank {get;set;}
}

 public class EmployeeBankMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<EmployeeBank>
 {
        public EmployeeBankMapping()
        {
           this.HasRequired(z => z.EmployeePaymentMethod)
                .WithOptional(zz => zz.EmployeeBank)
                .Map(zzz => zzz.MapKey("EmployeePaymentMethodId"));
        }
 }
```

If implement the above code, I found a one to many relationship has been created in the database.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can implement "one-to-one_or_zero" relationship with EF using ComplextType feature. However it is not clear from your code why do you need  EmployeePaymentMethod? I mean it just holds the "Id" field, maybe you could solve your case adding extra int field to EmployeeBank class?

Answer (score 1):

**Here it is using `DataAnnotations`.**

```
public class EmployeeBank
{
        public int Id {get;set;}

        public string Name {get;set;}

        public virtual EmployeePaymentMethod EmployeePaymentMethod { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeePaymentMethod
{
        [Key, ForeignKey("EmployeeBank ")]
        public override int Id {get;set;}

        public virtual EmployeeBank EmployeeBank {get;set;}
}
```

**Here it is using `Fluent API`**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeBank>()
       .HasOptional(e => e. EmployeePaymentMethod) // Mark EmployeePaymentMethod property optional in EmployeeBank entity
       .WithRequired(b => b. EmployeeBank); // mark EmployeeBank property as required in EmployeePaymentMethod entity. Cannot save EmployeePaymentMethod without EmployeeBank

}
```

Comment: According to your answer, there can't be more PaymentMethods, than Banks. So if there is only 1 Bank, you can have no more than 1 PaymentMethod. Does it make sense? Also is it possible to make column PK and ForeignKey same time?

Comment: @AntonMaiorov This is the only way which you can make an `One to One or zero relationship`.You cannot do it using any other way.

Comment: ComplexType is a feature to implement One to One. You solution looks more like a flag. I will give it a try in my VS, since I'm not sure that the DB structure will be generated successfully out of this code.

Comment: @AntonMaiorov sure,please go ahead and do that and let us know your findings :)

Comment: InvalidOperationException: Additional information: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Id' on type 'FkOverPkTest.EmployeePaymentMethod' is not valid.

Comment: @AntonMaiorov, is a non sense to have an autonumbering field as a foreign key.

Comment: I've tried Fluent API version with Data Annotations commented out. And it works for Sql Server.

Comment: @AntonMaiorov here is a good article about the above subject.Please read it.http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @AntonMaiorov hehe.. then you can Up-vote this solution no ? :D

Comment: Still  the second table acts like a flag.

Comment: @Sampath I'm still not sure what the QS wants to achieve) And I'm just having fun)

Comment: @Sampath The post is useful) One-to-One_or_Zero indeed. I see your point now. But if there is no other fields, except the Id, then it acts just like a flag.

Comment: @AntonMaiorov EmployeePaymentMethod Entity has a lot of fields. I just removed them for simplicity.

Comment: @Sampath I don't want to use this way because It's required to have independent Primary Key. Both Entities should have Auto Identity Number as a primary key.

Comment: you cannot create an `One to One or zero relationship` like that.That is by design on relational databases.

Comment: @Hammad Understood, trank you. I have one idea, I'll check it and post an answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EmployeeBank> EmployeeBanks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EmployeePaymentMethod> EmployeePaymentMethods { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeBank>()
            .HasMany(e => e.DoNotUseMeSir)
            .WithMany(b => b.DoNotUseMeSir)
            .Map(mc => mc.ToTable("BankToPaymentMethods")
            .MapLeftKey("EmployeeBankId")
            .MapRightKey("EmployeePaymentMethodId"));
    }
}

public class EmployeeBank
{
    public EmployeeBank()
    {
        DoNotUseMeSir = new List<EmployeePaymentMethod>();
    }

    public int EmployeeBankId { get; set; }
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [NotMapped]
    public EmployeePaymentMethod EmployeePaymentMethod
    {
        get { return DoNotUseMeSir.FirstOrDefault(); }
        set
        {
            DoNotUseMeSir.Clear();
            DoNotUseMeSir.Add(value);
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<EmployeePaymentMethod> DoNotUseMeSir { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeePaymentMethod
{
    public EmployeePaymentMethod()
    {
        DoNotUseMeSir = new List<EmployeeBank>();
    }

    public int EmployeePaymentMethodId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public EmployeeBank EmployeeBank
    {
        get { return DoNotUseMeSir.FirstOrDefault(); }
        set
        {
            DoNotUseMeSir.Clear();
            DoNotUseMeSir.Add(value);
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeBank> DoNotUseMeSir { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDatabaseInitialiser : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EmployeeContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(EmployeeContext context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);

        var employeeBankIdUc =
            "ALTER TABLE dbo.BankToPaymentMethods ADD CONSTRAINT uq_BankToPaymentMethods_EmployeeBankId UNIQUE(EmployeeBankId)";
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(employeeBankIdUc);

        var employeePaymentMethodIdUc =
            "ALTER TABLE dbo.BankToPaymentMethods ADD CONSTRAINT uq_BankToPaymentMethods_EmployeePaymentMethodId UNIQUE(EmployeePaymentMethodId)";
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(employeePaymentMethodIdUc);
    }
}
```

Then use it simply:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new EmployeeDatabaseInitialiser());
new EmployeeContext().Database.Initialize(true);

var context = new EmployeeContext();
var bank1 = new EmployeeBank{Name = "Bank1"};
var bank2 = new EmployeeBank {Name = "Bank2"};
var epm1 = new EmployeePaymentMethod();
var epm2 = new EmployeePaymentMethod();

context.EmployeeBanks.Add(bank1);
context.EmployeeBanks.Add(bank2);
context.EmployeePaymentMethods.Add(epm1);
context.EmployeePaymentMethods.Add(epm2);
context.SaveChanges();

bank1.EmployeePaymentMethod = epm1;
epm2.EmployeeBank = bank2;
context.SaveChanges();
```

I used Many-to-Many relation with additional UNIQUE constraints for both relation columns, this turns it into One-to-One_or_zero. Also you have independent autoincremented ids. This solution is not 100% Entity Framework, custom database initializer is required to put constraints in place.